How to validate string values in a list of string using playwright
I have a list of string values in a array.
I have to validate above array strings with the present titles are present in the application.
I have tried to validate multiple_Columns with headerTitlesPresent but my test case is failing.
can someone please suggest which assertion I should use.
const multiple_Columns = ["apple","banana","pine"]
const headerTitlesPresent = await homePage.header_Titles
expect(await headerTitlesPresent.allTextContents()).toContain(multiple_Columns)
await expect(headerTitlesPresent).toHaveText(multiple_Columns)


This is hard to follow and I don't see any issues with the synopsis/stub of the code you provided. Please share the actual, complete but minimal script, because it may be failing elsewhere than you assume. What's the exact assertion failure message? See [mcve] for guidance. Thanks.

@Bugbee - you need to separate your code from you question. Users on StackOverFlow do not like to see code included with normal text.

@TalAngel, Thank you. I will follow.

You can try my code:
const multiple_Columns = ['apple', 'banana', 'pine']
        const headerTitlesPresent: string =
            await homePage.header_Titles.innerText()
        let matches = 0
        multiple_Columns.forEach(function (value) {
            if (headerTitlesPresent.includes(value)) {
                matches++
            }
        })
        if (matches == multiple_Columns.length) {
            // full match
        } else {
            // not a full match
        }

